# Unit test error where it calls DocusignApi Apex toolkit method: dfsle.DocuSignAPIMock

Tags: unit-test, docusign

I am using Docusign Apex toolkit (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/statusservice.html) to generate a docusign url from following method

```
dfsle.StatusService.getViewUrl(docusingId,returnurl)
```

and want to create a unit test for the wrapping method. But got docusign unauthorized error.

So to resolve that I assumed I need to mock the callouts and seems like they have API methods for it.

So in test method I tried using following code and got an error:
Compilation error: **Type is not visible: dfsle.DocuSignAPIMock**

```
static testMethod void myTest() {
   dfsle.TestUtils.setMock(dfsle.DocuSignAPIMock.success());
   System.runAs(dfsle.UserMock.createDocuSignAdministrator()) {
     // Call service method requiring the DocuSign Administrator permission set.
   }
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked Docusign documentation or support resources?

Comment: @DavidCheng OP linked to the available documentation. It's not the worst documentation that I've seen/worked with, but it's far from the best. Documentation/resources on testing this stuff is pretty bare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not as up to speed on DocuSign's Apex toolkit (namespace "dfsle") as I was with their previous interface, but I do remember that testing was a pain point.

The [ESignatureAPIMock](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/esignatureapimock.html) and [UserMock](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/usermock.html) classes are I believe the only "mocks" available to us.

Using them required me to jump through some additional hoops, basically just using multiple `System.runAs()` blocks to get a different enough execution context to avoid the "Please commit or rollback before calling out" error.

The test code I had to write to be able to get the envelope preview URL (which I remember being 2 "callouts" deep) looks like this

```java
@isTest
    static void previewURL(){
        commonSetup();

        // An alternative here appears to be just 
        //   new  dfsle.ESignatureAPIMock().success() (or .failure())
        dfsle.TestUtils.setMock(new dfsle.ESignatureAPIMock());

        // This section is specific to my customizations
        // Basically, this is setup so I can call dfsle.EnvelopeService.getSenderViewUrl(envelopeId, targetUrl)
        Url result;
        PageReference pr = Page.DocuSignGeneral;
        pr.getParameters().put('id', testContract.Id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pr);

        helper.pdfDoc = Blob.valueOf('test');
        helper.contentVersionId = null;

        // Jumping through more hoops to get the envelope created by the same test user
        //   with the required permissions to call getSenderPreviewUrl()
        // createDocuSignSender() performs DML, and user is a setup object
        //   so any DML on non-setup objects (excluding work done in an @testSetup method)
        //   needs to be done in a system.runAs() block
        testDSUser = dfsle.UserMock.createDocuSignSender();
        dfsle.UUID envelopeId = dfsle.UUID.randomUUID();
        system.runAs(testDSUser){
            // If I recall correctly, inserting this envelope causes a callout
            //   which is why it's contained in a system.runAs() block
            // That, and/or we need docusign to generate an envelope id for the next
            //   call to work (wasn't able to figure out how to fake that Id)
            insert new dfsle__Envelope__c(
                dfsle__DocuSignId__c = String.valueOf(envelopeId),
                dfsle__Sender__c = testDSUser.Id
            );
        }

        helper.envelopeId = envelopeId;
        System.runAs(testDSUser) {
            Test.startTest();
            result = helper.previewUrl();
            Test.stopTest();
        }

        // Looks like the return url is not added to the result of getSenderPreviewUrl()
        //   in unit tests...
        String docusignUrl = result.toExternalForm();
        System.assertNotEquals(null, docusignUrl, 'returned url should not be null');
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't (for the OP) it be easier to wrap his method call to `dfsle.xxxx` into a service layer class and then mock that class in unit test methods using dependency injection?

Comment: Thanks Derek .. looks good.. I ended up using dfsle.ESignatureAPIMock() .. not sure if that is what being called during preview url generation.
@cropredy.. yeah that would be a good alternative.. since the code I wrote is custom logic.. I wanted to cover it with unit test as much as possible with Docusign methods and since Docusign has some mocking functionality . I thought why not..

Comment: the advantage of mocking frameworks like apexmocks is you can test that you passed the proper args to the method and mock any arbitrary URL as a result without having to know anything about the supplied Docusign mocking methods (which, to be fair, are useful and props to the vendor for including)